# What level of error expected when using NAD StatePlane CRS from adjacent state?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states, linear-referencing, state-plane

I am adding Georgia data to my GIS database and, unlike the California data I've added, have decided to use my existing EPSG:3361 (South Carolina StatePlane) coordinate reference system for calculations.

I've done this with reasonable success in North Carolina (South Carolina's northerly neighbor) but never did the research to determine the error suffered by using a linear reference system from a non-intended, albeit adjacent area.

I'm guessing the error shouldn't be more than 50 feet, am I correct in assuming this?

More technical information:

- here's the linear reference system I'm using in Georgia: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3361/
- here's the linear reference system I should be using in Georgia but am not: http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2239/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The northern two-thirds of Georgia should be pretty good, because the South Carolina coordinate reference system is Lambert conformal conic-based. Thus, the standard parallels extend through Georgia too. I ran a point at 31N 85W through the National Geodetic Survey's [SPC program](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/spc_getpc.prl) to see what the distortion would be. Note: South Carolina's zone is 3900. It returned:

```
 =======================================================
           Latitude           Longitude      Datum Zone
 INPUT =   N310000.0          W0850000.0     NAD83 3900
 =======================================================

  NORTH(Y)    EAST(X)     AREA  CONVERGENCE   SCALE
  METERS      METERS            DD MM SS.ss   
  ----------- ----------- ----  -----------   ----------
  -85051.112  227348.537  SC    -2 13  3.35   1.00086349
```

So the distortion is 1.00086349 or 86 parts per 100000 (or 8.6 parts per 10000). A State Plane zone was originally designed to be no worse than 1 part per 10000.

Comment: that sounds OK to me. What is that on a footage basis for your example point?

Comment: Sample point in state plane is in meters as that's what the NGS tool returns. The part per... structure is unitless so 86 meters per 100000 m or 86 feet per 100000 ft.